# Accessibility of multiple fields declared at the same line

Tags: c#, access-modifiers, class-members

I wonder if I do this all the variables will be public or just the first one:

```
public string equipamento, marca, modelo, descricao, observacoes, prioridade;
```

Or if I need to declare them like this:

```
public string equipamento;
public string marca;
public string modelo; 
[...]
```

The second option obviously works, but does the first one too?

Comment: Just did it, worked!

Comment: Note that many people would consider cramming multiple variable definitions in one line bad style, while very very few would consider it bad style to always have one definition per line.

Comment: Thank you, but i did it in one line for code reduction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in the C# language specification, section 10.4 Fields [on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645750(v=vs.71).aspx):

> A field declaration that declares multiple fields is equivalent to multiple declarations of single fields with the **same attributes, modifiers, and type**. For example
>
> ```
> class A
> {
>    public static int X = 1, Y, Z = 100;
> }
> ```
>
> is equivalent to
>
> ```
> class A
> {
>    public static int X = 1;
>    public static int Y;
>    public static int Z = 100;
> }
> ```

But as [commented by @hyde](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31101244/accessibility-of-multiple-fields-declared-at-the-same-line#comment50217812_31101244), consider the former bad practice. It actively harms the readability of your code.

Comment: I tought it would work. I made the question so others in future can have where to search.